# What Egit actions do I take to get copy of src file TESTGIT1 from MainServerRepository into LocalServerRepo to work on?

Tags: eclipse, egit, dvcs

As a new Egit user, aiming to set up version control to update the way a team manages source code without changing locations of our build and dev servers and to identify correct Egit commands to use for check in and check out code from both servers.

In a single Eclipse workspace, initially had one project without use of Egit just a basic automatic and adhoc file copy back up of changed development directory into folders with dates of backup. Promotion to the build server was done by manually copying source files and binaries, doing a diff between source on the MainServer and local server to manage any merges. Now need to implement a proper version control system, using Egit, so as a first time Egit user. I have set up two test Eclipse projects in my workspace: project A shared with MainServerRepository and project B shared with LocalServerRepo. The two git repositories will be in different directories: MainServerRepository on the network and LocalServerRepo on my area on the network where I backup my PC.

What Egit actions do I take to promote latest TESTGIT1.src from MainServerRepository into LocalServerRepo to work on in my local server? (Team > Fetch from upstream is grayed out). Then, once tested, how do I check in src for TESTGIT1 into the main build server project, source and objects are in MainServerRepository?

I've used Team > Commit successfully to check in, but am using cut and paste to move code between two projects (prior to commit) and feel there must be a better way to do this or to set up the projects differently within Eclipse.

Or should I be using Team > push or Team > merge?

Do I need local repository or should I just check out into workspace?

Any comments/ question/assistance would be welcome as haven't figured it out from reading the [EGit/User_Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

Comment: In (E)Git a commit is a local operation. You have to _push_ the commits to the remote/upstream Git repository. I don't understand what exactly you want to do, why you have two projects and whether these two projects are in the same Git repository. It would be helpful if you described the initial situation and the goal.

Comment: @howlger thanks for commenting - have edited question to clarify what initial situation is, what want to do and what the goal is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: TESTGIT1 commited to localServerProject]

Edit TESTGIT1.src in Eclipse project shared with LocalServerRepo(testGitRepo)  until work on it is complete  on local server.  Then, apply same changes to TESTGIT1 in the main build server project, using right click copy +paste from right click, team > check in. Then in Git Staging view, click plus sign to add to index (staging area), then click commit button, merging in with any other changes made to TESTGIT1.src by other developers. Don't use push command to push entire contents of LocalServerRepo. Or is there a better answer?